# how to show images at cell.imageview.image from NSArray?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview

```
Image Array=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1 (1).gif"],
            [UIImage imageNamed:@"1 (2).gif"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"1 (3).gif"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"1 (4).gif"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"1 (5).gif"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"1 (6).gif"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"1 (7).gif"],nil];

//here is another array of objects showing in table view

alphabetsArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"A",@"B",@"C",@"D",@"E",@"F",@"G",@"H",@"I",@"J",@"K",@"L",@"M",@"N",@"O",@"P",@"Q",@"R",@"S",@"T",@"U",@"V",@"W",@"X",@"Y",@"Z",nil];
    //everything working fine until when i add this code,app crashes with SIGABRT
cell.imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:[imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

Actually i need to ask some more things:

1. Is there any problem if number of images in array isn't equal to number of object in tableview?
2. Is there any other way to add images if they are huge in number except of uiimage imageNamed:"whatever.jpeg"
3. What if add a folder and give its address or name and it picks up images by itself..
4. What is most reasonable method of adding images in project if they are 250 in number(i-e sqlite,coreData,hardcode in project as i did)?

Comment: Try to see the crash logs to help you debugging the issue. There you will see that the method objectAtIndex throws exception if the index is more than the number of elements in the array, causing the crash.

Comment: what about other questions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, there is issue with this line `[UIImage imageNamed:[imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]`.

The `[imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]` is returning UIImage object in your current implementation, and you are trying to get UIImage with name of UIImage object.

You should just return the UIImage object directly to the cell.imageView.image.

```
cell.imageView.image = [imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Second, I am not sure how many rows are there in the table, but the method objectAtIndex can throw exception if the index is more than the number of elements in the array, causing app crash.

Answer (score 1):

1) There would be no problem with this, unless you want to have the same number. It won't throw an error, but your app logic will not work properly.

2) Not that i know of, It's easy to do this though, use an easy naming convention such as `image01`, That way you can just copy and paste the code and change the ending numbers of the image

3) Im not sure of what you are asking.

4) Typically you would just need to add the images to your project via `drag-N'-drop` or by picking the files. Core data and sqlite are for the actual app that you are developing, not to store images in Xcode.

As for the main question, You say you want to show the images from an `NSArray`, if thats the case, just get the index path of the tableview, and look up the corresponding image using `objectAtIndex:`

Hope that helps a bit :)

Comment: thanks for your time and a thorough answer sir ! in 3) i am asking that what if i drag an drop a folder of images in project, then how to access images in there?

Comment: You are welcome! And there is nothing wrong with dragging and dropping images into Xcode. By access do you mean via code? If so, you can use `UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image01.png"];` now you have a `myImage` object that you can use which will represent the `Image01.png` image. & If this was the answer you were looking for, please check the green check mark :)

Comment: but i need to add 250 images, how can i use this object with array?

Answer (score 1):

Actually i have figured something out , there is an easy way to do.

```
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.gif", [TextShownInTableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];
```

i have alphabetics in this array, and i wanted to use different images with each of the alphabet, so just added images in project with same name as alphabets had. it worked fine with this line of code. TextShownInTableArray is your array with text :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Image Array=[NSArray  alloc]initWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"8.gif"],
        [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.gif"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"3.gif"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"6.gif"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"5.gif"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"4.gif"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"7.gif"],nil];
```

your array alloc and that array 'retain' this array and try this code .thanks

```
[imageArray retain];
```

only change in your code this line . and solve your problem

```
cell.imageView.image=[imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

i hope this code useful for You . Check this

Answer (score 0):

```
cell.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(5, 5, 50, 50);

NSString *imgstr = [[Arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"thumb"];

cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imgstr]]];
```